# SqlException was unhandled by user code incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class Student_InsertStudentDeta : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMsg.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;
        btnFindValuse.Enabled = false;
        btnUpdate.Enabled = false;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into MoHE_Student values (N'" + txtName.Text + "',N'" + txtSureName.Text + "',N'" + txtFatherName.Text + "',N'" + txtGFatherName.Text + "',N'" + txtBirthYear.Text + "',N'" + txtNIDC.Text + "',N'" + txtTabdily.Text + "',N'" + txtTitalMonugraf.Text + "',N'" + ddlJeldBook.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + txtDescription.Text + "',N'" + ddlUniversity.SelectedItem.Value + "',N'" + ddlFaculty.SelectedItem.Value + "',N'" + ddlDepartment.SelectedItem.Value + "'," + txtStudentRegBook.Text + "," + txtPageBook.Text + "," + ddlReciveBook.SelectedItem.Text + "," + txtGraduateYear.Text + "," + txtRegYear.Text + ",N'" + ddlKoncurExam.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + ddlDefaMonugraf.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + ddlYearDefa.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + ddlMonthDefa.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + ddlDayDefa.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + ddlTakeDiplom.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + txtPhonNum.Text + "',N'" + ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + ddlDarajaTahsili.SelectedItem.Text + "',N'" + User.Identity.Name + "')", connection);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Error happens here
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @badruddin: please tag this with an appropriate language, and remove the `html` tag.

Comment: Things like `" + txtPageBook.Text + "` should be `'" + txtPageBook.Text + "'`, so a single quote is required to wrap concatenated string parameters, with N or without N. Use parameterized queries or stored procedures instead of this approach.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, and so is the reason. Whatever `txtName.Text` contains, it has at least one `'` and one `,`. Imagine what would happen if it contained `'; DROP TABLE MoHE_Student;--`. That's why you should *not* concatenate strings to create a sql statement. Use parameterized queries`

Comment: This is precisely what [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) refers to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: To add to what is written in other comments, you should always use the `using` statement when dealing with instances that implements the `IDisposable` interface - in your case that's `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate explains what's wrong, how serious this is and how to avoid it. I won't repeat the explanation here, simply because I started to, then my fingers started tingling. The various answers to the duplicate are adequate and even contain `Bobby Tables`.

This just shows how this particular code can be fixed.

First, the command can be created once and reused:

```
SqlCommand _insertCmd;

void InitCommands()
{ 

    _connectionString = 
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    var query = "Insert into MoHE_Student values (@name,@surname,...";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30);
    ...
    _insertCmd=cmd;

}
```

When the time comes to execute it, set the parameter values and open a connection *inside a using block* to ensure the connection is closed even if an error occurs :

```
_insertCmd["@name"].Value=txtName.Text;
...

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
      _insertCmd.Connection=connection;  
      connection.Open();
      _insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```